# Integrating over a variable to reduce PDE to ODE (SIR Model)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm following a paper that uses a PDE SIR model (http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0264410X11019025/1-s2.0-S0264410X11019025-main.pdf?_tid=1801e946-f28c-11e5-8f1a-00000aacb361&acdnat=1458912101_d9de124d36c3e052d87097303a83718e) and I've come across a system of PDEs such that I cannot easily see how the writer has reduced the system in one of ODEs. Here is the system of PDEs:

\begin{align*}
 &\frac{\partial S(t,a)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial S(t,a)}{\partial a} = \omega R(a,t) - S(a,t)[v(a) + \lambda(a,t)] \\
 &\frac{\partial E(t,a)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial E(t,a)}{\partial a} = \lambda(a,t)S(a,t) - E(a,t)[v(a) + \gamma] \\
 &\frac{\partial I(t,a)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial I(t,a)}{\partial a} = \gamma E(a,t) - I(a,t)[v(a) + \rho] \\
 &\frac{\partial R(t,a)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial R(t,a)}{\partial a} = \rho I(a,t) - R(a,t)[v(a) + \omega]   
\end{align*}

where $\lambda(a,t)$ denotes the force of an infection, $\gamma, \rho$ and $\omega$ are epidemic-related constants. S,E,I and R denote states of individuals at any age and time.

$v(a) =  \begin{cases} 
      0 & 0\leq a < 65 \\
      \frac{1}{25} & a \geq 65  
   \end{cases}$

$\lambda(a,t) = \tau\sum_{j=1}^c\Bigg[m_{ij}\int_{A(j-1)}^{A(j)}I(a,t)da\Bigg]$
where $m_{ij}$ are constants, c is a constant, $\tau$ is a contant as are $A(j-1),A(j)$.

The writer then compares the PDE numerical solution to 'the solution of the homogeneous mixing equivalent set of ODEs in time derived from **integrating the PDEs with respect to age** to obtain the following system of equations':

\begin{align*}
 &\frac{dS}{dt} = \mu N + \omega R(t) - S(t)[\mu + \lambda(t)] \\
 &\frac{dE}{dt} = \lambda(t) S(t) - E(t)[\mu + \gamma] \\
 &\frac{dI}{dt} = \gamma E(t) - I(t)[\mu + \rho]  
\end{align*}

Now I can easily see how $\int_0^{\infty}\omega R(a,t) da = R(t)$, and $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\partial S(t,a)}{\partial a}da = -\mu N$, but i struggle to see rigourously how $\int_0^{\infty}S(a,t)[v(a) + \lambda(a,t)] = S(t)[\mu + \lambda(t)]$. We can ignore $R$ since $R = N - S - I - E$. I do not understand how they've simply reduced the PDE but integrating over $a$.

EDIT: $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\partial S(t,a)}{\partial t}da = \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^{\infty}S(t,a)da = \frac{dS}{dt}$ is just the Leibniz integral rule, correct?

EDIT 2: $v(a)$ is an age-dependent mortality rate such that $\int_0^{\infty}v(a) = \mu$ where $\mu$ is the birth rate.

Comment: Yes, it looks to me as an application of the Leibniz rule.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any insight into how  $\int_a^{\infty}S(a,t)[v(a) + \lambda(a,t)] da = S(t)[\mu + \lambda(t)]$ ?

Comment: What a mess... Since the first system (of PDEs) does not imply the second system (of ODEs) in the setting the authors describe, you might decide to contact the corresponding author to ask for some explanations.